# Auth with laravel

Tags: laravel

I do not know why the auth of laravel not work to me..  I have tried all but it still does not work, I use this code to login:

```
   $user = User::where('rut', $request->rut)
                  ->where('password', md5($request->password))
                  ->first();

    $employee = Employee::where('id_user', $user->id_user)
                  ->first();

    $permissions = User_Type_Permission::where('id_user_type', $user->id_user_type)->pluck('id_permission')->toArray();

    $request->session()->put('id_user_type', $user->id_user_type);

    $request->session()->put('id_branch_office', $employee->branch_office);

    $request->session()->put($permissions);

    if(Auth::login($user))
    {
        echo 1;
        die();
        return redirect('/account');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 2;
        die();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

It returns "2" every time, and the user is not empty, it comes with values from database

I have used Attempt too:

```
   $user = User::where('rut', $request->rut)
                  ->where('password', md5($request->password))
                  ->first();

    $employee = Employee::where('id_user', $user->id_user)
                  ->first();

    $permissions = User_Type_Permission::where('id_user_type', $user->id_user_type)->pluck('id_permission')->toArray();

    $request->session()->put('id_user_type', $user->id_user_type);

    $request->session()->put('id_branch_office', $employee->branch_office);

    $request->session()->put($permissions);

    $credentials = [
    'rut' => $user->rut,
    'password' => md5($request->password),
];

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        echo 1;
        die();
        return redirect('/account');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 2;
        die();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

and it returns false too, the login information is correct, but Auth does not work at all, what can it be?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Laravel's built in register controller? Did you add a custom register method? Are you storing the passwords with `md5`?

Comment: No because it's a intranet so i do not need that the people register... the thing is that it worked before and it stopped to work, super weird and i have tried all and nothing happens @CésarEscudero, and yes the password is with md5...

Comment: I have checked the password or the select if it comes empty, and no, it comes with data from database...

Comment: use here `'name' => $user->name,` cause auth and attempt will work name and password

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I already figured out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove md5.. if you store the hashed password by bcrypt..
Auth::attempt() automatically check the plain text password in the request with the hashed in the database.
So the code should be

```
 $credentials = [
    'rut' => $user->rut,
    'password' =>$request->password,
];

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
        echo 1;
        die();
        return redirect('/account');
    }else{return redirect('/login')}
```

And put all the code you have written in the top to the true condition..
what you write is not correct ..
if authenticated make what i want..
Not put the code then check if authenticated!
I Hope this work with you!
Good luck!